# C# - Sharing resources file between project

Tags: c#, resources

I would like two how to do to share Resources files between 2 (or more) projects?

So, to resume, I've three project :

the development project (CF.NET) that include the resource file (with all definition).

I've two other projects that are empty BUT linking to the development projects, it's just a different build each time, so when I modify the development project, all three projects are updated too. (Modification of the csproj file.)

Question is, what about Resources files? When I try to access from the development project I get all resources but when I try from the 2 others, it throws an "MissingManifestResourceException".

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks.

---

**[EDIT]**

Here is what I've done :

Create a project named "RealProject" which contains all code (including resources files)
Create a project named "LinkedProject" which contains nothing (I deleted all files into it and modify the csproj file as the following :

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="..\RealProject\**\*.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

So in LinkedProject directory I've only :

- [Directory] bin
- [Directory] obj
- [File     ] LinkedProject.csproj

The whole LinkedProject uses the RealProject files, it's just a different configuration build (see here to know why : [C# - Code compiler for .NET & CF.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109026/c-code-compiler-for-net-cf-net/) )

Once in that configuration, I've no access to the resources files from the RealProject ...

If you need screens or more detailed explanation, just ask.

---

**[EDIT]**

With this code, it works, Resource manager isn't loaded on the good Assembly name, but it should exists a better solution !!!

```
Assembly ass = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(@"..\..\..\RealProject\bin\Debug\RealProject.dll");
ResourceManager manager = new ResourceManager("RealProject.Properties.Resources", ass);
```

---

**[Solution]**

Things to check :

- The LinkedProject as the same
  namespace as the RealProject
- Add Resources as links
- Clean up all your solution
- Rebuild it

Test !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to add the resource file **[as a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)** to the other two projects and make sure the namespaces as defined in the project file is the same.

Comment: First thing a tried, doesn't work. (My two other projects are already linked to the first one !)

Comment: What exactly do you mean, when you say, the projects are linked?

Comment: With that "hacked" project file, you are only including *.cs files. What happens, if you also include *.resx files?

Comment: @Arnaud F.: I am not sure, whether or not my comment showed in your Inbox, that's why I am writing you again.

Comment: In fact, it is already included... But see my second edit please :) (is coming)

Comment: @Arnaud F.: What about a namespace mismatch? I think, if your linked project has a namespace like `LinkedProject` and your main project has a namespace like `MainProject` configured in its project file, this will lead to the error.

Comment: They have the same namespace ;)

Comment: @Arnaud F.: Does anything in this link help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327692/c-what-does-missingmanifestresourceexception-mean-and-how-to-fix-it

Comment: I won't believe it... I just cleaned all my solutions up, rebuild it, retried and ... works !

Answer (score 1):

Try adding existing file in other projects as a link.

Comment: First thing a tried, doesn't work. (My two other projects are already linked to the first one !)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with sharing resources files between different projects is that the root namespace has to be the same in all the projects you use the same file in.

Or not.

**You can get the root namespace at runtime** in the `*Resources.designer.cs` file. Note the links in the comments to related answers. Make sure you commit this and keep an eye on it, the code-generator has a habit of overwriting it which would break its universality. I used the xml doc comments to remind me what's going on, if the code-gen obliterates it I'll see it in the commit diff.

```cs
/// <summary> Returns the cached ResourceManager instance used by this class.  </summary>
/// <remarks> DO NOT commit any version of this file the tool overwrites, it will break it for other projects</remarks>
[global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
public static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
    get {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) 
        {
            // https://stackoverflow.com/a/1329631/492 https://stackoverflow.com/a/51978052/492  
            Assembly thisAssembly = typeof(/*thisClassName*/).Assembly;
            // you need a class called "App", or just change the name on the next line to one you have in the root namespace
            var apps = thisAssembly?.GetTypes().Where(t => t.Name == "App");

            if (apps.Count() != 1)
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Too Many App classes. Count: {apps.Count()}, Apps: {apps}");
            
            Type appType = apps.FirstOrDefault();
            string ns = appType.Namespace;
            global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager($"{ns}.OtherNames.Spaces.thisClassName", typeof(thisClassName).Assembly);
            resourceMan = temp;
        }
        return resourceMan;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering a post of 9 years old ;)